# Typescript fails to consider `never` functions when checking values

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
function neverEnd(): never {
    throw Error('Error');
}
```

I use it in another function like so:

```
function useNever() {
    const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const found = array.find(x => x === 2); // found is number | undefined

    if (!found) {
        neverEnd();
    }

    // Here we know for a fact that found is a number
    const double = found * 2;   // Typescript complains that found may be undefined
}
```

Why does Typescript miss the fact that `found` can't be undefined at this stage?

Comment: What version of typescript does this fail on? [This playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGApgNxQJwKJgCYAUAlAFzLpaIDeAUIvYlABaZwDui2mrmBA5Fx58iAbhoBfGjVCRYCRCADOKAHIVeRanQYQEiqIgCG3QwE9EAXkQBtAIwAaRACZHAZkcAWRwFYAumIZEXTB9RGA4cDxLIxNTADpgGHwCAA9LAD5ENIsc51FEAHoCsIj8RBhFZBAAWwAjSgAfBXwURNQ8KUCYYEQCAEJwyM1aQMDUDBxk0W16SRnC4oAJLBRENlWAazB2EswjMMNoRiZDA0Gyiv2wGvrMeeDQvAjagBtVq3OogCpnEQYixAAFVMAAcUIoIJgYCCDLpqiCXoYkpVmKcSpFENUzIh6s08K0kigOuIgA) shows your exact example working

Comment: Also, as a side note, your example will throw an error if the number or other value you're ever trying to find is falsey.

Comment: Weird. I'm using Typescript 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

This is just not possible (at least now)

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219) you may connected issue and discussion.